# Measuring debug vs release of ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, performance, testing, memory-management, measurement

**Which has the biggest impact?**

- Building ASP.NET applications in release vs debug mode
- Setting `<compilation debug="true">` in web.config

Has anyone done any testing to get actual numbers about what the differences are, considering performance and memory usage? (Perhaps other metrics are useful as well?)

*For example, something like:*

```
Execution time     | Debug build   | Release build
-------------------+---------------+---------------
Debug web.config   | average 1     | average 2
Retail web.config  | average 3     | average 4


Max memory usage   | Debug build   | Release build
-------------------+---------------+---------------
Debug web.config   | average 1     | average 2
Retail web.config  | average 3     | average 4


Output file size   | Debug build   | Release build
-------------------+---------------+---------------
                   | size    1     | size 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that explains the drawbacks.

http://www.aspnetresources.com/articles/debug_code_in_production.aspx

In my opinion it seems to affect 'web site' applications more than 'web project' application.